# Converting Android Library API to Kotlin

Tags: android, sdk, kotlin

I recently read articles about Kotlin and I can't really wait to use it with Android development.

I'm writing on an Android library, which shall be provided as some kind of SDK.

Assuming I would switch to using Kotlin within my library. Are there any downsides for users of that library who are not using Kotlin?

What adaptions are required for users if the SDK is included

- as a module (with source code)?
- as a dependency?

Comment: This is too board, opinion based, should be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why the question should be opinion-based. I'm asking for the technical adaptions a Kotlin library requires.

Comment: In Stack Overflow questions that are too broad, or opinion based do not fare well.  You are to show what you tried already to resolve a problem, what you discovered, and what your remaining problem is.  Without any of that, it is overly broad.  People will likely also assume you did not do any homework before asking.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll do more homework and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation on interop of Java accessing Kotlin code can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

I believe adding the sdk as source code would only require the normal setup for getting kotlin code to work under normal circumstances, which are documented at the same site. Just go to the Tools section on the left, and include the build info required for your specific builder.

As a dependency, it will just be a jar as usual, compiled to java byte code so there's nothing needed (except maybe the runtime library, which *should* be automatically pulled in as a sub dependency).

In either case, please take the interop practices into account when designing the library.